# Sqlite3 terminal- how do I copy the last query to the command prompt?

Tags: sqlite

If I want to edit & rerun the previous command in sqlite3, presently I have to retype the query from scratch. It doesn't seem to support the 'arrow key' method you often get in terminal programs.

Running on Ubuntu.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Did you compile it yourself?

Comment: Nope, it came with anaconda

Answer (score 0):

In windows and ubuntu `up` key works fine.

Comment: Just tried it again. When I press 'up' I get ^[[A - this time on a different machine (Ubuntu also). This is running in an SSH terminal.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/561087/strange-keyboard-when-using-sqlite-shell-on-linux

Answer (score 0):

Readline support must be enabled. Clean easy solution is here:

https://superuser.com/a/82447/87610